# Submit form on input text change

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I know this question has been asked a million times, but I can't seem to get anything to work. I am trying to have the value of the input change when I click one of the links which is working fine, but I'd also like to submit the form automatically as well, without a submit button as soon as a link is clicked. At the moment it doesn't work unless I click the input field. Also I can't add id's to the links. This is what I have so far.

```js
var $Form = $('form'), $Container = $('#container');
$Container.hide();
$Form.on('click', function(p_oEvent){
    var sUrl, sMovie, oData;
    p_oEvent.preventDefault();
sMovie = $Form.find('input').val();
    sUrl = 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + sMovie + ''
    $.ajax(sUrl, {
        complete: function(p_oXHR, p_sStatus){
            oData = $.parseJSON(p_oXHR.responseText);
            console.log(oData);
            $Container.find('.title').text(oData.Title);
            $Container.find('.plot').text(oData.Plot);
            $Container.find('.poster').html('<img src="' + oData.Poster + 

'"/>');
            $Container.find('.year').text(oData.Year);
            $Container.show();
        }
    });    
});

$(function () {
    $('a').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#text');
        text.val($(this).text());    
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">rocky</a><br>
<a href="#">Back To The Future</a><br>
<a href="#">Spaceballs</a><br>

<form id="omdbform">
        <input type="text" name="movie" placeholder="movie title"  id="text" onchange="this.form.submit();">
</form>

<div id="container">
    <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
    <span class="year">Year</span>
    <span class="poster">Poster</span>
    <p class="plot">Plot</p>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Added link examples
`<a href="/family_photos/filename1.jpg">filename1.jpg</a>
<a href="/family_photos/filename2.jpg">filename2.jpeg</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your link function to below :

```
$(function () {
    $('a').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#text');
        var fileName =$(this).text();
        fileName = fileName.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
        text.val(fileName);    
        $Form.click();
    });
});
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, How would I remove file extensions? As some of the links have extensions and I need to remove them.

Comment: Give me an example for that.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
var $Form = $('form')
$Container = $('#container');
$Container.hide();
$("body").on("submit", "form", function(p_oEvent){
    var sUrl, sMovie, oData;
    p_oEvent.preventDefault(); sMovie = $Form.find('input').val();
    sUrl = 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + sMovie + ''
    $.ajax(sUrl, {
        complete: function(p_oXHR, p_sStatus){
            oData = $.parseJSON(p_oXHR.responseText);
            console.log(oData);
            $Container.find('.title').text(oData.Title);
            $Container.find('.plot').text(oData.Plot);
            $Container.find('.poster').html('<img src="' + oData.Poster + 

'"/>');
            $Container.find('.year').text(oData.Year);
            $Container.show();
        }
    });     });

    $('a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = $('#text');
        text.val($(this).text());
        $("form").submit();
    });
```

Before using the "on" read http://api.jquery.com/on/